# How to make code changes show when using yalc

Tags: reactjs

I learn [yalc](https://github.com/wclr/yalc) and do exactly what it say but when I change the library code that I have done `yalc publish` on, I can't see the code changes in my app.

The library is [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack)

Steps:

- yalc publish in the notistack
- I then run `yalc add notistack` in my App or `yalc link notistack`

When I then change the notistack code and run `yalc push` then nothing happens but docs say I should get the code change in my app?

I even restart the App server and do the `yalc update notistack` but the notistack code changes is not visible.

The strange thing is in my app VSCode node_modules I see the `notistack` code changes. It's like the `yalc push` is propagating the notistack changes to the app but the app is not using them.

It's even more strange that when I restart VSCode and start the App Server to do debugging the old notistack code is still used.

I test to remove the `yalc remove notistack` and restart laptop and then do again `yalc add notistack`. I then see the old code again.

I tried in Chrome Browser to do hard reset empty cashes but no luck getting this to work.

When I go and look in yalc Store:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Yalc\packages\notistack\1.0.10\src:

I see the latest code.

In Chrome Inspector Console I see old code but under Inspector source the correct code is there. This is so confusing. I can't set breakpoints either, not in Inspector or in VSCode, breakpoints in the notistack. It's like the JavaScript files are dislocated.

This happens in both Edge and Chrome.

What I do now after two days to be able to continue work I must delete that Yalc store folder,,C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Yalc\packages\noti...............
deleted yalc.lock in app project
delete package-lock.json and node_modules

Then start over publishing and adding the notistack. It's time-consuming but works.

How can I make code changes show in Yalc?

package.json for notistack

```
{
    "name": "notistack",
    "version": "1.0.10",
    "description": "Highly customizable notification snackbars (toasts) that can be stacked on top of each other",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "module": "dist/notistack.esm.js",
    "types": "src/index.d.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        "name": "Hossein Dehnokhalaji",
        "email": "hossein.dehnavi98@yahoo.com",
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack"
    },
    "homepage": "https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/notistack",
    "repository": {
        "url": "git+https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack.git",
        "type": "git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsdx build --transpileOnly --entry ./src/index.js",
        "prebuild": "npm run docs",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
        "docs": "rimraf typedoc.json && typedoc --tsconfig",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0",
        "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "clsx": "^1.1.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/issues"
    },
    "funding": {
        "type": "opencollective",
        "url": "https://opencollective.com/notistack"
    },
    "contributors": [
        "Hossein Dehnokhalaji (https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/)"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "notistack",
        "enqueueSnackbar",
        "snackbarprovider",
        "useSnackbar",
        "multiple",
        "react",
        "javascript",
        "material-ui",
        "toast",
        "redux",
        "snackbar",
        "stacked",
        "notification",
        "material design",
        "hossein",
        "dehnokhalaji",
        "iamhosseindhv"
    ],
    "yalcSig": "073ef039ed1e473029c88b6ad9af16d9"
}
```

**UPDATE**

Adding App package.json

```
{
  "name": "greta-thunberg-fff",
  "version": "1.2.9",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://greta.portplays.com",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "comma-separated-values": "^3.6.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase": "^7.23.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.5",
    "framer-motion": "^2.9.5",
    "gsap": "^3.5.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.11",
    "material-table": "^1.69.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "my-notistack-fork": "file:.yalc/my-notistack-fork",
    "normalize-wheel": "^1.0.1",
    "npm": "^7.11.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.357",
    "preval.macro": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-activity": "^1.2.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^6.1.0",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-resize-detector": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.41.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "three": "^0.85.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.10.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=6545&& react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "clean-tag": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not so much clear. I would suggest to post all the code (or at least a short working piece); clearly state what you change; clearly state which is the result; clearly state which is, instead, the expected result.

Comment: @DanieleRicci the test-lib is [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack). I just fork it and try to `yalc link` or `yalc add notistack` to my app. I think notistack has some configurations maybe that I have missed because I cant git this to work.  Would be good if someone else try this? finding the problem I really want to use this lib

Comment: No sorry this is not clear as well. You are speaking about `yalc link` or `yalc add`.. but they have two completely distinct meaning.. is not clear which is your target. Let's forget for a while about `yalc link`, you forked notistack, and you are trying to add notistack to it with `yalk add notistack`? Why? I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and rephrase your question. I also checked https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-lib and it seems something 4 years old... It's really hard to help you without a clear reference to your library

Comment: Probably I got it, you have an app server and you want to add to it a forked and modified version of notistack; then you need to change simultaneously your app server and your modified version of notistak (they live in two distinct directories with two distinct `package.json` files). Am I right?

Comment: @DanieleRicci Yes your right exactly I should not sad "test-lib" when it was notistack. I know I miss something silly because I have another react App that do `yalc add..` succéfulla

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear I hope. I want to develop on my forked notistack that all

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your setup using `yalc add notistack` and noticed that `yalc push` doesn't compile the package. It worked when I added the flag `--scripts` as described in the docs:

> `scripts` options is false by default, so it won't run pre/post scripts (may change this with passing `--scripts` flag).

You can also run `yalc publish` and then `yalc push`, or `yalc publish --push`

For the changes to take effect in the app, I had to run `npm start` again.

This is how the notistack dependency looks in the package.json

`"notistack": "file:.yalc/notistack",`

**UPDATE**

As you pointed out, I also tried renaming the package to `my-notistack-fork` by changing the name in `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "my-notistack-fork",
    "version": "2.0.2",
    "description": "Highly customizable notification snackbars (toasts) that can be stacked on top of each other",
```

then removing the notistack dependency in my app with `yalc remove notistack` and adding it again with the new name `yalc add my-notistack-fork`. After that I made changes to the lib code and ran `yalc publish --push` and I could see them reflected when running again the app. The dependency looks like this

```
  "my-notistack-fork": "file:.yalc/my-notistack-fork",
```

Interesting that, for me, in the app node_modules, the lib directory has compiled files, and the error in your screenshot has an `src` dir which gives the impression that it is uncompiled [image: node_modules]

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried as you say and it worked first time around and second time but third  time I change notistack code and then run yalc publish and yalc push and restart app server  it stopped working. I tried it a third time and same problem  is back. Please confirm in your setup??

Comment: @Kid I made five updates, and for each one, I ran `yalc publish --push`, it worked as expected every time. Did you see the building complete successfully for the last 2 publish commands? That's the only thing I can think of. Maybe the last change you made broke the build

Comment: Thanks, strange. look here on the [picture](https://snipboard.io/8EnQcM.jpg) . It can't compile as you see it uses the node_modules version of notistack(my-notistack-fork). But it should use the one in the .yalc folder as you see in the package.json .

Comment: I look in the app .yalc folder and the code changes are there

Comment: @Kid it's curious that the dependency is called `my-notistack-fork`, I'll try to reproduce that locally, did you change the name of the package in your fork `package.json`?

Comment: Yea I change the name and [npm publish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-notistack-fork) it. That's all I changed. Someone sad I must have it published  to make this work.

Comment: Here is the [my-notistack-fork](https://snipboard.io/dV27Dn.jpg)

Comment: wait a minute maybe I should not change to src `"main": "src/index.js",` It was `dist` when I did `npm publish` I figure I must change it to src when using it in VSCode right ??

Comment: hey @Kid, I tried renaming the package, and still works. I noticed that the error in your screenshots says something about an src dir, which in my case doesn't exist in node_modules. Probably when you tried the npm approach something broke for yalc. I suggest sticking with one approach, if you go with yalc try undoing the npm link and then reinstall with yalc, delete node_modules, and run `npm i --no-cache`

Comment: Thanks for your update, I changed `"main": "src/index.js"` to `"main": "dist/index.js"` and `yalc publish` so now my node_modules looks like yours and also I can start server and app. All changes in lib now show in app like you say but;
Code changes [show in Chrome navigator sources](https://snipboard.io/Uz3LlC.jpg)  but they [dont show console ](https://snipboard.io/Z1bLlY.jpg). I tried hard loading chrome page flush cashed also. I'm happy to get this fare thanks

Comment: I restart laptop and run it again and get the same result it's like a ghost in the machine  here. Code changes  show in Chrome navigator sources but not in the app when running it. I also try running without debug. Where is chrome debugger getting the old code from

Comment: BOUNTY EXPIRE NOW i WILL START ANOTHER BOUNTY IF THIS IS NOT RESOLVED

Comment: @Kid did you change again the name of the lib to notistack? The first screenshot shows notistack/src. Could you add `package.json` to your post?

Comment: Thanks, It sas notistack in the screenshot I see it to I swear I did not change name. This is getting spoke really . Give me some time I must do something. Is it possible if you can do  a TeamViewer session remove control? I can pay you in Paypal money. I run a fast high end Asus I7 Intel laptop. UPDATE adding package.json for the app

Comment: please friend me at Facebook, 
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100016526263449

Comment: Chroma Navigator sources show "notistack/src", that's the name of the folder only even I changed the project name in package.json to my-notistack-fork. The forked original GitHub notistack folder name. Anyway I'm getting nowhere with this as the two screenshots above show. I will post another question please stand by

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly everything, I see two problems:

1. forking an npm package
2. working simultaneously with two packages

First of all I have to admit I do not know `yalc` but after taking a quick look to it, I would say it seems to work as `npm` does; I'll provide my answer with `npm`, I leave up to you to adapt my answer using `yalc`; but I'm pretty sure it's just matter of running the `yalc` command rather than the `npm` one, using the same parameters.

**1. forking an npm package**

If I understood correctly you are not the author of `notistack`, you have your own fork of it, but I still not understood its name.

Could it be you forked `notistack` and you didn't changed its name?

So, when we want to fork a package we need to give it a new name, let's say `my-notistak-fork`; the `package.json` file should seems something like:

```
{
    "name": "my-notistack-fork",
    "version": "new version progression numbers",
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        ... describe yourself
    },
    "homepage": "a new homepage, if you have one",
    "repository": {
        "url": "URL of your fork"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "URL of issues in your fork"
    },
    "funding": {
        ... if you have one, describe it
    },
    "contributors": [
        ... who contribute to your fork
    ],
    ...
}
```

I wrote only the filed which needs to be changed, the others could be left untouched (but this depends on how much you change the package, anyway this is another topic).

Publish it with `npm publish` command.

Now you have published `my-notistack-fork` which is a clone of `notistack` (at version you forked it).

**2. working simultaneously with two packages**

With `npm` this is something trivial and it works very well.

1. In the root directory of your local cloned `my-notistack-fork` repository issue the `npm link` command.
2. In the root directory of your local app server repository issue the following commands:

   1. `npm add my-notistack-fork`
   2. `npm link my-notistack-fork`
   3. `npm install`

That's all. Now changing files in each of the two repositories should immediately reflect on your debugging/development environment.

Probably cleaning the root directory of your local app server repository before doing that could be a good idea. I mean:

1. removing the `node_modules` directory
2. removing any lock file (`package-lock.json` and/or the `yalc` one)
3. removing any reference to `notistack` from you `package.json` file

Comment: Thanks, do you mean when you say "Now you have published my-notistack-fork.."  That I should do `npm publich` or `yulc publish`. Just asking before trying your steps. Your right I did not change the name of the forked notistack since I cant see that that was needed, I hope your right

Comment: HI @Kid . With "Publish it" I meant `npm publish` . Once done "Now you have published..."

Comment: @danielericce sorry I just now running your solution. But why do I have to `npm publish`, that will make  my lib available at https://www.npmjs.com/ even it's not ready to be publish. Running `npm install` . now after flushing everything lets see if it's working ...

Comment: Hi @Kid , you "need" to publish it, even if not ready yet, just to create the entries in the npm registry; this is required to make `npm add`, `npm link` and `npm install` to work correctly. To be more precise, I don't know if there is a way to make `npm link` to work without a published package; The way I suggested, is the most commonly used pattern, it is tested and we know it works.

Comment: I get the infamous Invalid Hook Call Warning duplicate react error when uing npm link that why I use yalc. I get strange [error](https://snipboard.io/iokXh1.jpg) now. Why is it using the node_module version and not the .yalc folder version of the my-notistack-fork

Answer (score 1):

Personally this fixed it for me:

> `yalc publish --push` will publish your package to the store and propagate all changes to existing yalc package installations (this will actually do update operation on the location).

The short-hand for the above is `yalc push`. Personally I use:

```bash
yalc push --scripts --update --replace
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/wclr/yalc#pushing-updates-automatically-to-all-installations), this:

- runs pre/post scripts
- force replaces the package contents
- runs `yarn update`

I made this a script on the package.json of the library I was testing:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "yalc:update": "yalc push --scripts --update --replace"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yalc with Vite, this is what you should be doing:

1. In the project that is being imported make sure that `/imported-project/dist/imported-project.es.js` contains your latest changes (search for a certain text for example). For me it was the '`npm run buil-lib`' command:
   `"build-lib": "vite build --config vite.lib.config.ts"`
   where `vite.lib.config.ts` contains the
   `fileName: (format: unknown) => 'imported-project.${format}.js',` line
2. `yalc push`
3. delete the .vite folder from the importing project:
   `/importER-project/node_modules/.vite`
4. `npm run dev`

This works consistantly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
yalc publish --push
```

or

```
yalc push --script
```

should work. In eariler yalc version, `yalc push` also works.

I came here try to find out why `yalc push` doesn't equivalent to `yalc publish --push` right now, but didn't get a clear answer.
My colleage said his behaviour is as expected while I'm not. His version is `1.0.0-pre.50` and Mine is latest `1.0.0-pre.53`.
I then understand what happened and goes to check the source code and [found](https://github.com/wclr/yalc/commit/dc543730df6f14bdf995078de19c6d05816c2303#diff-7d3e358f3120dd68edc7a32bbd18e8de8a75701bd1df62555aec0b64bdcbe7faL113) that, yalc changed the default value of parameter `--scripts` to `yalc push` from `true` to `false`  at `4/7/2021`, after [`1.0.0-pre.50`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc/v/1.0.0-pre.50) was released (1/19/2021). This is why before version `1.0.0-pre.50` (and including), `yalc push` equivalent to `yalc publish --push`, but after that version, you need to use `yalc push --script`.